# Symfony 4 default_locale is not working on Security library messages

Tags: symfony4, symfony-security, symfony-4.4, symfony-translator

I am building single language Symfony (v4.4.7) application.
As I understood from the documentation I need to set

```
framework:
    default_locale: tr
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - en
```

in config/packages/translation.yaml
to change lang in the whole application.

Using configuration above custom translations are working!
However, Symfony Security library still showing messages in English (e.g `Invalid credentials.` when user password is incorrect).
Removing `default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'` line does not help.
I tried to change the `default_locale` to other languages still the same result.

Edit 1 more details:
Content of translations directory:
[image]

`messages.tr.yaml` contains following lines:

```
security:
   roles_label: "Roller"
   roles:
       ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: "Super Admin"
       ROLE_ADMIN: "Admin"
       ROLE_USER: "Genel Kullanıcı"
```

I deleted content of the `messages.tr.yaml` and tried again but it is still not working. Other `tr` translation files does not contain `security` keyword

Comment: hey! did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem here

Comment: Did you generate translations files for Turkish like `security.tr.yaml`?

Comment: @onionpsy no I don't work on that project anymore.

Comment: @Liscare No I did not generate Security translation file since Symfony has it in its package

Comment: @NuryagdyMustapayev Can we see the content of the folder called: `translations`?

Comment: @Liscare added details you asked

Comment: It seems that you have problems with domain, see [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#the-translation-process). Specify your domain (`security` in this case), because the default one is `message`. If you use Twig, see [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/templates.html#using-twig-tags). Also you can generate security.tr.yaml file with this command `php bin/console translation:update --force tr --output-format yaml`